# JS ES6 template literals and leading/suffix zeros to number

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-literals

In Python it's possible to append leading zeros to number when building a string like this

```
print "%02d" % (1)
//>> "01"
```

Is it possible to do the same with ES6 template literals?

(If, is it also possible to do the same with spaces instead of zeros:  " 1"?)

Comment: It might be possible using tagged template literals, but really you'd just use `x.toString().padStart(" ", 2)`. Of course you can write your own `printf` function (or use any existing library).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the string function `padStart` by converting the number to string with `toString()` and then padding with `padStart` where the first argument is the length and the second is what to pad with.

```
let n = 1;
n.toString().padStart(2, "0")
//=>"01"
```

Comment: It solved my need. It's just not as "elegant"/pythonic as python

Answer (score 3):

You could try prepending the maximum width as a fixed string of characters to the value then slice the resulting string to size.

Example: Let's say you want your numbers left padded with a period to a maximum width of 6

```js
console.log((`......${123}`).slice(-6));  // ...123

console.log((`......${12345}`).slice(-6)) // .12345

const v = 99;
console.log((`......${v}`).slice(-6))     // ....99
```

Comment: One of my projects is a command-line app that has a feature to create a new Git branch using the format nnnn-slug where nnnn is the four digit left zero-padded story number followed by the sluggified version of the story title. 


let branchName = '${('0000${storyNumber}').slice(-4)}-${slugify(storyTitle)}';

SO comment processor is interpretting backticks as inline code fence so I have changed to singlequote. If you copy this code CHANGE single quote back to backticks

Answer (score 2):

If your numbers can only be between 0 and 99 then try this:

```js
for (let n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
  console.log(n.toString().padStart(2, "0"));
}
```

If you want to use spaces then try this:

```js
for (let n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
  console.log(n.toString().padStart(2, " "));
}
```

If you don't want to use `padStart` then try this:

```js
for (let n = 0; n < 100; n+=5) {
  console.log(('0'+n.toString()).slice(-2));
}
```

Or even this:

```js
for (let n = 0; n < 100; n+=5) {
  console.log(`0${n}`.slice(-2));
}
```

This last one uses the ES6 literals but still uses the `slice` to only get the last 2 characters.

To use spaces on the last two just change the `0` to ` space.

`String.padStart` is only available on newer browser versions. So you might need a polyfill.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

Comment: I very much doubt that OP wants to _remove_ digits from their number if it's more than 99. Most of the time people just want to zero-pad their number up to a certain number of digits.

Comment: It makes no sense to use `padStart` *and* `slice`.

Comment: @Bergi I cleaned up my response and answer the OP exactly since they asked about ES6 string literals and using spaces as well as a `0`. There is no reason to down vote my answer.

Answer (score 2):

A compact way of doing this, avoiding toString().

```
let n = 3;   
n = ("0"+n).substr(-2); // n === "03"
```

-2 is the desired length multiplied by -1. Change "0" to the max number of characters to pad.
For %03d:

```
let n = 3;   
n = ("00"+n).substr(-3); // n === "003"
```